# Multiple events triggered when adding event handler to body element

Tags: javascript, event-delegation

I have some markers in a google map; I'd like add a listener to the body element, which will detect if the element clicked has a certain class and do certain actions if so.

Now, everytime I click on target element, the event is triggered for all of the items which have the class in question.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  if (e.target.className === "price-bubble") {
    // do stuff
    console.log("hit target");
  } else {
    // do other stuff
    console.log("not hit target");
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  border: 1px solid;
}
.price-bubble {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="map">
  <div class="room-marker">
    <div class="dot" style="display: block;">
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div class="element">
        <div class="icon"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bubble">
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div class="element">
        <div class="price-bubble">12,20&nbsp;€</div>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="bubble">
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div class="element">
        <div class="price-bubble">12,20&nbsp;€</div>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="bubble">
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div class="element">
        <div class="price-bubble">12,20&nbsp;€</div>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="bubble">
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div class="element">
        <div class="price-bubble">12,20&nbsp;€</div>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="bubble">
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div class="element">
        <div class="price-bubble">12,20&nbsp;€</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is a simple typo in your code  `=`=> `==`

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `===` for comparison.

The value that is returned from an assignment expression (e.g., `variable = 'value'`) is the value that was assigned. Since this is a non-empty string in your case, the result is 'truthy' and so the `if` statement always succeeds.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  if (e.target.className === "price-bubble") {
    // do stuff
    console.log("hit target");
  } else {
    // do other stuff
    console.log("not hit target");
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  border: 1px solid;
}
.price-bubble {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="map">
  <div class="room-marker">
    <div class="dot" style="display: block;">
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div class="element">
        <div class="icon"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bubble">
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div class="element">
        <div class="price-bubble">12,20&nbsp;€</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks - this was one mistake but I have a new error. upvoting your answer

Comment: I may be able to help you with your new problem, but I am not sure exactly what behavior you desire. Are you looking for a way to determine which element was clicked?